# Deploy from Xcode 4.6.2 to iOS 7 (beta) device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I installed iOS 7 yesterday to test in my iPhone 5. The problem is that I can't deploy now any test applications from Xcode to my iPhone as it says it has an unsupported version. I can't (or don't want to) downgrade from iOS 7 to 6 and don't want (can't) upgrade Xcode to version 5 as submitting is not supported with Xcode 5 Beta.

So how do I deploy apps from Xcode 4.6.2 to iOS 7 Beta?

Comment: you have to use xcode 5

Comment: Strange. I have iOS 7 on one device and I have no problem using Xcode 4.6.2 to build and run apps on the iOS 7 device. Perhaps the difference is that I do also have Xcode 5 installed and have used it to build an app on the device. Maybe doing that first allows you to then use Xcode 4.6 with the iOS 7 device. It's a great way to test an existing iOS 5/6 app to see if it works normally on iOS 7.

Comment: If I install 5 they can coexist? Any trick needed?

Comment: Sure, you can have both Xcode 4.6.2 and Xcode 5 installed at the same time. No trick needed. Both go in the /Applications folder. Xcode 4.6 is named Xcode.app. Xcode 5 is currently named Xcode5-DP.app.

Comment: I'm  wondering why I have answered to this question

Comment: If you can't install Xcode5 for some reason, check my answer below

Answer (score 90):

Well I don't know If this is of any help to anyone but me. But I have been able to use Xcode 4.6.2 to deploy to my iPhone 5 running iOS 7. I think it is due to a bug in the system but it doesn't matter to me. It works OK. Now to do this, I do as follows:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode from the App Store. (I don't know why, but why not?)
2. Download and Install Xcode 5.
3. Close all instances of Xcode running in your system (4.6.2 and 5)
4. Run Xcode 5. you will see it recognizes your device, you probably have to activate it as use it for development again.
5. Run Xcode 4.6.2 simultaneously. You will see it recognizes your iPhone as in: make it valid target for development.
6. close or do whatever you want with Xcode 5. From this point onwards You can keep using Xcode 4.6.2

I haven't turned my computer off or restarted it in a long time so I don't know if this is a fluke or what. But other people I work with have been able to do the same, so I expect it to work for you.

EDIT:

Better yet. Something I have found useful is building from Xcode 4.6.x to an iOS 7 device, actually makes the phone run it in iOS6 or before Mode which is the way all apps run at the moment. So my guess is that this would be what your app would look like in iOS 7 if deployed from the app store. Assuming you are targeting iOS 4+

Similarly, if you build the same app using Xcode 5, it tries to incorporate some iOS 7 appearance proxies by default and certainly the UI behaves differently. Granted I haven't played with Xcode 5 much, there is probably a toggle somewhere to turn this compatibility mode on and off.

Comment: this sounds like a great way of doing it. I will give it a shot tonight!

Comment: @Dan1one I cant find way to add provisioning profiles in Xcode5. We cant test our application on device using xcode5?

Comment: @iVishal Well that is a different problem altogether. I'd say it is an issue with your provisioning, Xcode 5 will inherit the provisioning you have in Xcode 4 so unless you have some crazy settings in your project that prevent you from building to your device: 

- Check your organizer (CMD + Shift + 2)

Comment: - Check your organizer (CMD + Shift + 2)
- Make sure your device is authorised for development
- Either way give it a right click from the organiser, click 'add device provisioning portal' and make sure your team provisioning portal is installed on your device.

Comment: I believe I did this process previously and I could deploy to iOS 7 from Xcode 4.Then after awhile I couldn't deploy to iOS 7 device from Xcode 4 again. So I redid this process and now it works again...

Comment: I can't believe this worked, thank you! Not only can I avoid using Xcode5 a little longer but, more importantly, this **lets me test my iOS6 mode app on iOS7 devices** (and fix a few visual bugs) - something that doesn't appear to possible using Xcode5.

Comment: Nice, this trick still works with Xcode 5.1.1 & Xcode 6 (beta). I use it to test my iOS 7 SDK built apps on iOS 8 (beta) devices.

Answer (score 11):

I was unable to upgrade MacOS from 10.7.5 to 10.8.x and that is why I could not install Xcode5 on my MAC. I downloaded Xcode5 but due to incompatibility it can not be installed.

I was able to run app using XCode 4.6 in debug mode on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7
(and can't express enough how happy i got after that)

Steps:

1. Use incompatible Xcode5 (copy it from the dmg image to somewhere else, there will be a cross sign in it) and right click on it and Click "show package contents".
2. Go to **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs** and copy the iPhoneOS7.0.sdk file in the corresponding folder in Xcode4.6 after showing its package contents.
3. Go to **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** and copy the 7.0 and 7.0.3(11B508) file in the corresponding folder in Xcode4.6 after showing package contents.

Now when you open Xcode4.6 your project Base SDK should be 7.0 and if your device is not detected yet, disconnect and reconnect your device so that it starts "getting symbol files from iPhoneXYZ"

Hope this helps someone.

One more important thing, in your scheme Debugger should be set to "LLDB"

Answer (score 8):

You can't. But you can have multiple version of xcode installed 4.6.x and 5.0.

once installed the 5.0 you can do something like this :

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5.0.app
```

you can obviously switch back to the 4.6.x doing the same

Answer (score 4):

the best way I've found is.

In Organizer, add iOS 7 ipsw file to "Software images" then unplug and replug the phone. tada! you should be able to deploy build on your iphone.

Comment: I didn't think this would work but I just tested and can confirm that it does!

Comment: Actually ignore me, after I restarted my machine this no longer worked.  I assume it was due to me loading XCode 5 previously and that recognizing my device then ...

Comment: I've been using same technique ever since. :S

Comment: One thing -- the ipsw file is just referenced, not copied into the Organizer -- put it where you want it and don't delete or move it afterwards.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me (using Xcode 4.6.1 on OSX 10.7.5).

Comment: This works! You probably need the precise IPSW for your device's hardware though, i.e. there are different IPSW files for iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5 Model A1428, iPhone 5 Model A1429, iPadBlahBlah... (The exact "Model" of an iPhone 5 is written on its back.)

Comment: OK, now it doesn't work anymore, after I installed this IPSW on the device (previously had beta), and installed iTunes 11, which included closing and re-opening Xcode; I don't know what exactly caused it not to work anymore. Quirky stuff. -_-

Comment: Just to add another data point, I tried upgrading some things (Xcode 4.6.3 on OSX 10.8.5), and it still doesn't work for me. Also by the way I added the exact ipsw file that I used to install iOS7 on my device.

Comment: I did same, but after copying ipsw file & restore ipad mini, i got an error message.So again it was upgrading to ios 7 latest version.Any solution plz tell me its urgent, bcz I can't test my appklication on real device

Answer (score 4):

In order to deploy from Xcode 4.6 to an iOS7 device all I had to do was install the new iTunes 11.1 beta 2 from the iOS Dev Center website (in the iOS7 GM seed section).  No need to have Xcode 5 installed.  I can now use Xcode 4.6 to fix the minor issues my app has with iOS7 and submit to the app store, retaining the iOS6 interface until I have time to give it a makeover for iOS7 (using Xcode 5).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not to use the simulator here (though there are ways to [enable the iOS7 simulator on Xcode4](http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/testing-xcode-4-ios-6-sdk-app-on-ios-7-device/), but use real hardware instead. You probably have an iOS7 fueled device by now ;-)

If you only need to have your app deployed on iOS7 while using XCode4 [Damon's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951213) is sufficient. Debugging is limited to the log files :-/ but in my case it is the only solution, since I cannot install Xcode5 at all (waiting for the New Mac Pro ;-)).

So in that case

1. Archiving the product (Product > Archive) will compile as intended without warnings. Choose the base SDK flavour you like, but I recommend using the original (6.x?) instead of 7.
2. From Organizer distribute for Ad Hoc development using the matching profile on your iOS7 device.
3. Install the .ipa file on your iOS7 device using iTunes.

A bit of a hassle, but the most stable way if you don't have XCode5 installed.

Comment: i just want to add that this approach is working 100%! thank you very much for the information :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have both XCode versions installed.

Apparently, you can try launching XCode 5 and try building the app from there.
After that, close XCode 5 and run XCode 4.6.2. and try building for the same device.

Although I have iOS7 on my device. I'm still able to build using XCode 4.6.2. Upon restarting the phone though, it may be disabled and you have to do the same procedure again.

Answer (score 2):

We needed to install the beta version of XCode 5 on another workstation.
With that version you can provision the iOS 7 device for development.
Back on the normal production workstation with XCode 4 you add the provisioning profile to the iOS 7 device (now that Organizer actually recognizes it.
Then build and deploy the code through XCode 4 to the device.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install my app from XCode 4 on my iPhone running iOS 7 via ad-hoc distribution using my development provisioning profile.

Comment: I also got this to work via ad-hoc distribution. It's the only real way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One more way might be helpful for any developer.In Xcode 5 , 
Open organiser->devices->

ActiveDevice-->Applications-->(select any application deployed for ios <= 6.0 and having some considerable big size)-->download-->start Extracting.

Now you can see that the xcode stops recognizing the connected device until the download completes (green highlighted pointer becomes yellow for a while) , meanwhile in the gap remove the connector cable.

You are Done . Now , you can simply connect your device to xcode <= 4.6 .

I am using the same.
Sorry for poor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't debug iOS 7 directly, but you can use the Organizer in XCode to view logs. You do this as follows:

1. Deploy to the device as normal (run, or create an ipa file and push
   to device) **Note:** If you run the application, XCode will go through
   it's standard processes and fail on execution. Just stop the
   application at this point.
2. In XCode 4.x, open the Organizer.
3. Navigate to Devices and open up the device that you have connected
   to your Mac.
4. Select Console for your device.
5. Clear the current logs by selecting the Clear button at the bottom.
6. On your device, run the application manually.
7. Now in the Console, you should see any logs that you've put in place in the code.

This isn't the most efficient way to debug, but it's definitely better than not having any way to do it at all. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple start up partitions/drives, you can install Xcode 5 on one disk. Start up with that system and validate the iPhone for development. Then restart in the other disk with Xcode 4.6 and it will still be recognized as a development device and allow apps to install/test/etc.
I've done this and it works fine for me. I have OS 10.8 and Xcode 4.6 on my "main" drive, and OS 10.9 and XCode 5 on another ("testing") drive.
Works for me, but this could change with any later OS or XCode update of course.

Answer (score 1):

I got an analogous problem in iOS8 bets era using xCode 5.1

xCode refuses to recognize my iPhone 5, (yellow pin..).
You can fool xCode using a symbolic link (xCode will assume it can handle ios8.. too)

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1\ (11D167) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0\ (12A4265u)

Comment: This got me going in the right direction for iOS 8 Beta 2, but the target for the symbolic link I made references Xcode6-Beta2.app, not Xcode.app. Worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i had installed the dmg of xcode 5 preview. You must to run first xcode 5 and run your app on the simulator, then you must open the xcode 4.6 and when you test your app in the ios 6 simulator, the ios 7 simulator starts to run and you can developp your app in xcode 4.6 and test it in ios 7.

This was very useful for me. I hope it can be useful for you

bye

Answer (score -1):

I was able to deploy application from XCode 4 WITHOUT having XCode 5 & iOS SDK 7 installed.
It is possible using an IPA file (I wasn't able to deploy directly from XCode 4) and:

1. iPhone Configuration Utility (add to application list and then
   navigate to device list/applications/install)
2. TestFlight App

In both cases you should have valid provisioning profile associated with your certificate used to created IPA and target device.