# The version of iOS on “mydevice_name” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode4.6.3

I have just updated my iPad with iOS 7.0 (11A465), and as per the instructions I have installed the iTunes compatible with it ie 11.1, but my iPad is not getting detected in xCode.
my xCode version is 4.6.3.

and organizer shows message as below:

The version of iOS on “myDevice_Name” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on myDevice_Name iPad
7.0 (11A465)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions

I stuck in this problem, even I am getting problem for testing my apps on device, so please help me out for this issue.

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode 4.6.3 comes with iOS6.1, hence XCode will not detect your iOS7 device. It can detect any device with iOS version <= iOS6.1 and allow you to use it for development.

If it is just matter of installing app on your iPad, you can use iTunes for that. But if you want to connect device to XCode for debugging or using Instruments then you will need to upgrade to XCode5.

---

**EDIT**

There seems to be [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143960/1407017) that has worked for few people. But it still requires installing Xcode 5. Xcode does not recognise a device with higher iOS version than available with it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is not entirely true.  I have a development partner using 4.6.3 and his iPhone 5 with iOS 7 is being recognized by Xcode.  However, I can't get mine to work.  So I don't have an answer but I know it is possible.

Comment: Thanks... that did the trick and should be the answer to the poster's question.

Comment: Thank you all..... but now its solve my problem. I have downloaded xcode 5, and after that my device gets detected on my both the xcode ie, xcode 5 as well as xcode 4.6.3. Thanks for your valuable responses.