# The version of iOS on “my_ipad” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am using xcode(5.0.2) and my device is having 7.0

The version of iOS on “Bhavesh iPad” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK.

OS Installed on Bhavesh iPad
7.1.2 (11D257)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions

Thanks in advnace

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 new update V 7.1(11D167) not compatible in Xcode 5 for development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317379/ios7-new-update-v-7-111d167-not-compatible-in-xcode-5-for-development)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to update your iPad or XCode to the latest version. The current version right now clashes with the iPad's OS (as it has already stated) and is thus unstable.

You can try to work around it. Check out this previous question: [The version of iOS on “mydevice_name” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959203/the-version-of-ios-on-mydevice-name-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-of-t)