# Why is my iPad mini not detecting in Xcode after updating it to iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have updated my iPad Mini to iOS 7. After doing this, when I connect it to my Mac Mini running Xcode 5, my iPad doesn't show up in Xcode.

Without this I can't test my iOS applications. How can I force Xcode to detect the iOS 7 device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your XCode is updated and working, then your problem could be that you have to add again your device to the portal, it happened to me.

From XCode 5:

Window -> Organizer

Then select your device, and press in "Add to Member Center":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Antonio MG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113019/why-is-my-ipad-mini-not-detecting-in-xcode-after-updating-it-to-ios-7/19113137#19113137) seems to have solved your specific problem. But for those who've updated their device to iOS7 *without* upgrading to Xcode 5, note that iOS 7 is not supported by Xcode 4 etc...

So download the update version of Xcode (Xcode 5.0) from the developer site and install it on your Mac before attaching your iOS7 device.

Check the connected status of the device in the Windows --> Organizer. It should show the Green color in the name of the connected device.

For further discussion of using Xcode 4.6 with iOS 7, see: [Deploy from XCode 4.6.2 to iOS 7 (beta) device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075894/deploy-from-xcode-4-6-2-to-ios-7-beta-device)

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating to iTunes 11.1.1 fixed this.  The device has 7.0.2